# asp.net webform System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations Validate.TryValidateObject is not working

Tags: asp.net, regex, webforms

I am validation data fields from the UI with the  System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace and using the Validate.TryValidteObject method. I am able to get [Required] to validate,  but not RegularExpression and StringLength. These two always come back true. Here is my code

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
var result = new List<ValidationResult>();
                        bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(irAddress, new ValidationContext(irAddress, null, null), result);



        /// <summary>
        /// The first line of the address
        /// </summary>
        [StringLength(5)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9 .'-]+)$", ErrorMessage = "Address line contains illegal characters.")]
        // [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required.")]
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The second line of the address
        /// </summary>    
        [StringLength(60, ErrorMessage = "Maximum address line length is 60.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9 .'-]+)$", ErrorMessage = "Address line contains illegal characters.")]

        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
```

Comment: Here is the corrected code

Comment: Is there any question here, or have you answered it already?

Comment: If you have already determined your answer, you should post it as such (i.e. answer your own question).

Answer (score 0):

OP: "after more googling, I found this answer."

```
bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(irAddress, new ValidationContext(irAddress, null, null), result, true);
```